# 'CKR_ENCRYPTED_DATA_INVALID' while calling close() method on CipherOutputStream in sun platform(after JDK 1.8.011 )

Tags: java

My code is failing on sun platform with every latest version of java after jdk 1.8.011 but with other platforms its working fine.Before jdk 1.8.011 its working fine in all platforms:

> Caused by:java.security.ProviderException:doFinal() failed
>       at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Cipher.implDoFinal(P11Cipher.java:776)
>       at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Cipher.engineDoFinal(P11Ciphe.java:543)
>       at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Cipher.engineDoFinal(P11Ciphe.java:526)
>       at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2048)
>       at javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream.close(CipherOutputStream.java:210)
>
> Caused
>   by:sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception:CKR_ENCRYPTED_DATA_INVALID
>   at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_DecryptFinal(Native Method) at
>   sun.security.pkcs11.P11Cipher.implDoFinal(P11Cipher.java:769)

It is failing while calling close() method on CipherOutputStream.
       CipherOutputStream.close()

Please give any fix so that it will work with latest version of java in all platform.

Comment: What is your code doing, can you share a sample? Regarding the JDK version, is it 1.8.0_11 , there isn't a version like 1.8.011.

Comment: My code is decrypting an encrypt file using algorithm:DES, Padding:PKCS5Padding,Mode: CBC.It is a platform specific issue.It is working fine in windows with all versions of java,but only in sun platform it is failing with every latest version of java after jdk 1.8.0_11.